# Firefox pushes table content up one pixel

Tags: firefox, push, pixel

I'm pulling my hair out over this probably very simple problem..

I just built a website for an iphone repair company:
http://www.cellcity.co.nz/

When viewed on google chrome and safari the website shows up without any problems, 
when viewed on internet explorer i just have the mobile optimised version showing while i get around to sorting out its problems.

but on firefox all my elements are pushed up one pixel. I have all the content within a table within divs, have a quick look at my source code or request some code to be shown. I don't understand what could be wrong, I am using the border-collapse css style, maybe that might be a contributing factor?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out that for every css class and id, you can make a firefox independant one that is only seen by firefox. Just place  @-moz-document url-prefix() {.....} around the second version of your css class and firefox will override the old version =D

hopefully this helps someone else!